# Data Annotations in MVC , Required is not showing on button click

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, visual-studio, model-view-controller

I am practicing MVC Web Application .NET Framework . I got confused here as I have already installed  NuGet package of jQuery Library of Unobtusive.Validation but still Required Field is not working. Here is my class of Student

```
    {
        [Required (ErrorMessage ="Student Id is required")] 
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Name is required")]
        public string  Name { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Email is required")]
        public string Email { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Contact is required")]
        public string Contact{ get; set; }
    }
```

and here is StudentData.cshtml file in which the combine code of c# and Html.

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Student Data";
}

<h2>StudentData</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    
<div class="form-horizontal">
    
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Id, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Id, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Id, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Email, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Email, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Email, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Contact, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Contact, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Contact, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Save Record" class="btn btn-primary" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
}
```

How can I solve this.
I have already reinstall the NuGet package `Unobtusive` latest version.

Comment: What validation is not working? Client or server? And I think you have to show how are downloading javascript libraries.

Comment: Client side validation is not working and a NuGet package is required named "Unobtusive" which i have installed 2 times, You can also check this from github link:   https://github.com/nabeel-1998/WebApplication7.git

Comment: Did you check in the browser for the errors and  if all of this jquery libraries are downloaded?

Comment: there is no any need of such libraries only NuGet package required for this. You can also check this project on github. Link is already in comment

Comment: For example, Chrome has  a developer tools. You have to open this and check for the error and check html code.

Comment: Do you actually have references to the javascript libraries in question in your page?  If not, then they will not be loaded.  Mereliy installing them as a nuget package is only half of what you have to do, you need script tags that reference them in your views.

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered the same problem before. I think the javascript files of the program are in conflict with each other, it is better to check how to introduce the project javascript files.

Answer (score 0):

For the client-side validation to work you need jQuery, the [jQuery Validation plugin](https://jqueryvalidation.org/) and [jQuery Unobtrusive Validation](https://github.com/aspnet/jquery-validation-unobtrusive). You can load all three of them from a CDN, for example:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.19.1/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validation-unobtrusive/3.2.11/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
```

You can add the script references to your view to test if it works, but normally you would add jQuery to _Layout.cshtml and the other two to a partial view called _ValidationScriptsPartial.cshtml. This is the default configuration if you use the latest project template.

Review the required configuration here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation?view=aspnetcore-5.0